# How to delete rows from recyclerView and sqlite database both?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app with recycler view and SQLite database. When user enters some data, it is displayed in recycler view and also added to my database. Now I want to implement `delete` functionality in recycler view.

**What I want:**

I want to delete the required row from database and also from recycler view at the same time, without getting any unexpected results. And all the rows should be deleted.

**What I've Tried:**

> I've implemented `onLongClickListener` on `cardView` of recycler view (I'm using cardView as the row of recycler view). now when use long clicks its, I'm getting adapter position. and delete the entry of database at that position.

But this gives me unexpected results like: All the rows deleted which are below the actual deleting row or the row which are deleted once appears back when the activity of recycler view is again created and never deleting last 2-3 rows, which database entries are deleted already.

My code of adapter of recycler view is:

```
public class AdapterForMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForMain.ViewHolder>{
ArrayList<String> mDataset;
ArrayList<String> mfooterSet;

private int[] icon;
MainActivity context;
DatabaseHelper myDb;


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    // each data item is just a string in this case

    public TextView txtHeader;
    public TextView txtFooter;
    public ImageView imgView;
 //   MainActivity mainActivity;

    CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);

                int detingPos = getAdapterPosition();
                boolean isDeleted = myDb.deleteEntry(detingPos);

                if(isDeleted){
                    mDataset.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),mDataset.size());

                }
                Toast.makeText(context,"Delete from here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       // Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        context.detailActivity(getAdapterPosition(),mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()),mfooterSet.get(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}


// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public AdapterForMain(ArrayList<String> myDataset, ArrayList<String> myFooterSet, int[] images, MainActivity context0) {
    icon = images;
    mDataset = myDataset;
    mfooterSet = myFooterSet;
    context = context0;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public AdapterForMain.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  Toast.makeText(AdapterForMain.this,"Settings Activity is under Construction.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.txtFooter.setText(mfooterSet.get(position));
    holder.imgView.setImageResource(icon[position%1]);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}}
```

And code of `delete` method:

```
    public boolean deleteEntry(int row) {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_1 + "=" + row,null);
        return true;
    }
```

I've seen the following link for the solution but can't get exact solution for what I want.

> [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695229/how-is-the-position-of-a-recyclerview-adapter-related-to-the-index-of-its-datase)
>   [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444127/how-to-remove-an-item-from-recyclerview-after-removing-it-from-database)

Comment: After deletion you have to load the adapter again to the recyclerview

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: @pskink I don't want to use custom adapter.

Comment: @kgandroid but how to reload this? and what about some other unexpected results mentioned above?

Comment: now you are using a **custom** adapter, the one i posted is a generic `Cursor` adapter

Comment: at first make sure that your deletion query is correct.After that implement the longclick of the recyclerview in the fragment AND NOT IN THE ADAPTER.In the fragment,load the adapter again to the recyclerview after deletion.

Comment: And avoid  notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),mDataset.size());

Comment: Y dont u move your `setOnLongClickListener` to `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: then Which is perfect place for this? @AlexChengalan

Comment: Is your `COL_1` Primary_Key? Is it also Autoincrement?

Comment: yes @Marat  its a primary key and autoincrement

Comment: @kgandroid isn't my delete method correct?

Comment: seems to be correct.Check it through debugging and make sure that the right one is deleted.Then do what i said.It will work.This is a common problem with adapter deletion with recyclerview/listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to pass `long` to your delete method and **not** `int`. Secondly, your should pass the **exact rowId** to your method and **not** the adapter position. Because adapter position will always be continuous set of numbers from 0 to some number without gaps between, while in your database you will have some numbers not used for rowId after deletion of data from table. For example, if you delete the 5th row then index 4 is not used any more by SQLite db. Your will have rows like 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6... Because it is autoincrement.

I will advice you to store your data in two dimensional array or ArrayList. Then you need to pass values of `COL_1` too with the corresponding text when retreiving data from db. That way you will be always aware of which row number contains particular data and show that row number when you want to delete it.

Because you have only one column for data, it will be easy to show you the version with two dimensional array.

You can imagine it as array of arrays:

mDataset ->

*at positions:*
**0   |   array1

1     |   arrays2

2     |   array3**
...   |   ...

array1 ->

*at positions:*
**0   |    rowId

1     |    textData**

array2 ->

*at positions:*
**0   |    rowId

1     |    textData**

and so on. But you will need to change the code of method for retreiving data from db so that it will return the above mentioned ArrayList.

The code will look like below:

In your DataBase:

```
// getData method
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COL_1, COL_2};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    int rowId = c.getColumnIndex(COL_1);
    int text = c.getColumnIndex(COL_2);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add(c.getString(rowId));
        temp.add(c.getString(text));
        data.add(temp);
    }

    return data;
}

// deleteEntry method
public boolean deleteEntry(long row) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_1 + "=" + row, null);
    return true;
}
```

DataSet:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mDataSet = //initialize or pass data
```

then use it as:

```
int position = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition).get(0);
boolean isDeleted = myDb.deleteEntry(Long.parseLong(position));
```

or

```
long position = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition).get(0);
boolean isDeleted = myDb.deleteEntry(position);
```

Comment: okay I understand what is the problem in my logic. But the change in my code is: `int position = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition).getRowId();`

Comment: I can't understand `.getRowID()` part.

Comment: you can easily do that by using [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) generic `Cursor` adapter, and not by using `two dimensional array or ArrayList.`

Comment: @pskink you are ri8 that we can easily do this with generic Cursor adapter but for that I've to change my whole code. and there is possibility of too many errors by me.

Comment: @Kaushal28 ok, it is up to you what you do, go back to that generic `Cursor` adapter when you are tired of fixing your custom adapter

Comment: @Marat, `mDataset` is a list wich I'm initializing in constructor. So I've to change the parameters in `MainActivity` also, from which I'm initializing this adapter?

Comment: @Kaushal28 you will need to change just the datatype of `mDataSet` everywhere it is used. The datatype inside of parameters and in MainActivity will need to be changed

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but with which value should I initialize 2D list in constructor?

Comment: @Kaushal28 it is given in the answer: the datatype is `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. The initialization is `new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Comment: Not that initialization. See the constructor in my code after onClick method.

Comment: @Kaushal28 leave code in your adapter as it is for mDataSet. Just change the datatype from `ArrayList<String>` to `<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and that's all for it. The rest of the changes are described in my answer

Comment: It solved the problem a lil. Now deleted rows not appearing again. But all the data below the 1st deleted row is also deleted.

Comment: Check if the required row is deleted from the db itself, not in arraylist inside of adapter.

Comment: Now problem is in viewing the data. Nothing is displayed when I click on the card view. So I think there is problem in line `context.detailActivity(getAdapterPosition(),mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()).get(1),mfooterSet.get(getAdapterPosition()));` in onClick method

Comment: @Kaushal28 I think the problem is in method `onBindViewHolder`. Change these lines `final String name = mDataset.get(position).get(1);
    holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).get(1));`

Comment: Thank you bro +1  and accepting the answer. It solved the problem.

Comment: @Kaushal28 Glad to know that problem is solved. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Kaushal28 ok see this 40 lines of working code: http://pastebin.com/WTxUBGd5, just long click on the item and watch the logcat and compare it to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` concept

Comment: @pskink Could you write your comments under author's question? I constantly receive notification about your comments

Comment: i wrote it here because i wanted to let you know as well, your solution of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` is basically wrong when it comes to data structures

Comment: @pskink I prefer to use `ArrayList<DataModel>`, but I don't see any problems in using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` too. Moreover, there are many questions and answers in SO that use arraylist of arraylists. Could you explain what is wrong with that?

Comment: ok first ^C^V my solution, run it and read my 40 lines of code, if still in doubts return here and i'll try to explain whats wrong with your solution

Comment: @pskink how the solution is wrong when it comes to data structures?

Comment: @pskink I have never used that 3rd party adapter. But I think your solution is aimed at optimizing his adapter code. It is really short and clear. However, I don't see problems with arraylist of arraylist. In addition, the question was to delete the data properly from SQLite db and I just said that author needs to pass `rowId`. My solution is one of the many that can store and pass required `rowId`.

Comment: and my solution in method `onLongClick` prints out the `rowId`, the value returned by `getItemId` method

Comment: As I said, my solution is one of the many. Your solution will do a great job too. So, what is wrong with `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` ?

Comment: ok, first of all, you are duplicating data: this is the `Cursor` which stores all that data so what is the reason of duplicating it in your `ArrayList` (the adapter i pointed to just uses that `Cursor` to provide the data), also you are duplicating the whole data set which can lead to OOM error (you are wasting both memoty and CPU time), note that `SQLiteCursor` extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` which stores the data in a small `CursorWindow` thus allowing to handle even huge data sets, third, what you already noticed the inner `ArrayList` is extremely inefficient to store just two `String`s

Comment: I agree with you about the efficiency of using `Cursor`. Actually, I was aware of existence of CursorAdapter, but never looked at it. When learning the android I noticed the tutorials and articles in web use both approaches without any problems. I think statements like you made come with the experience. Moreover, the author already build his app architecture around RecyclerView adapter. For him this would be the probably the shortest solution. However, I've learned something from this discussion. Therefore, I would like to thank you! Willing to come across to `OOM` kind of errors to learn more

Comment: BTW `Cursor[Recycler]Adapter` gives you an easy item filtering: `FilterQueryProvider` - something you cannot implement easily with `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter` / `RecyclerView.Adapter` and for a `ListView` there is a version of `CursorAdapter` that can be used in just 3-4 lines of code: `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting the object from Sqlite by its row id

```
// Deleting single contact  
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {  
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",  
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });  
        db.close();  
    } 
Deleting object from RecyclerView:
```

RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    parseArgument();

    adapter=new ReviewRecyclerAdapter(reviewArrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    reviewArrayList.remove(contact);//pass contact you want to delete
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```